# chart.js 2.7.1 - polar area chart has too much padding

Tags: chart.js

When updating from 2.7.1 I've found the Polar Area Chart has changed something about how it is displayed. There's now a lot of padding on either side of the graph, so that it no longer fills the div in which the canvas is placed.

I've got screenshots of the same output using 2.5.0 and 2.7.1
[image: Here's the output using 2.5.0]

[image: Here's the same output using 2.7.1]

Everything other than the version of chart.js being used is the same in the two screenshots.

Is there a way to fix this so that I can stay up to date with 2.7.1 and get the output I want, as it looks using 2.5.0 ?

Thanks,
Scott

Here's an example of the output:

```js
//helpers = Chart.helpers;
var trimergencePolarData = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [
      41,
      38,
      35
    ],
    backgroundColor: [
      "rgba(103, 182, 93,.75)",
      "rgba(182, 87, 56,.75)",
      "rgba(83, 134, 155,.75)"
    ],
    hoverBackgroundColor: [
      "rgba(103, 182, 93,1)",
      "rgba(182, 87, 56,1)",
      "rgba(83, 134, 155,1)"
    ]
  }],
  labels: [
    "Intuition",
    "Emotion",
    "Logic"
  ],
  relativeLevel: [
    "Primary",
    "Secondary",
    "Tertiary"
  ],
  activation: [
    "Higher",
    "Higher",
    "Middle"
  ]
};

window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("polar_chartjs").getContext("2d");
  var mytrimergencePolarArea = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: trimergencePolarData,
    type: "polarArea",
    options: {
      startAngle: Math.PI * 1.166666666667,
      layout: {
        padding: 18
      },
      elements: {
        arc: {
          //borderColor: "#000000"
        }
      },
      scale: {
        ticks: {
          min: 5,
          max: 50,
          stepSize: 5,
          display: false
        }
      },
      animation: {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: "easeOutQuad",
        onComplete: function() {
          var imgBlob = mytrimergencePolarArea.toBase64Image();
          //console.log(imgBlob);
          //document.body.appendChild(imgBlob);
          data = {
            "taking_id": 15,
            "action": "trimergence_store_image",
            "img_type": "polar_chart",
            "imgdata": imgBlob
          }
          jQuery.post("https://trimergprogrms.wpengine.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(msg) {
            // do nothing for now
          });
          //});
        }
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltips: {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.6)",
        bodyFontColor: "rgb(255,255,255)"

      }


    }

  });


};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="polar_chartjs"></canvas>
```

Note the change in chart size (padding) if you change the version of Chart.js from 2.7.1 to 2.5.0

Comment: Please posta a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added an example runnable as a code snippet... changing the Chart.js version between 2.5.0 and 2.7.1 shows how the size of the chart changes.

Comment: SOLVED: apparently due to a change in 2.7... can be fixed by using the option aspectRatio: 1

Comment: how did you get the labels out of the grid, I'm looking for this solution since long time... thx

Comment: The labels around the polar chart are actually a background image... so they aren’t created dynamically with the chart (ie, I have to create those separately and then set different background images for different data sets)

Comment: @Vemuez - setting the option aspectRatio: 1 fixed the padding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting option aspectRatio: 1 fixed the padding issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your new `chart.js` to old 'chart.js' ver 2.5.
And polar ares chart will get normal size.